# phpunit warning on an utilitary class

Tags: php, phpunit

I use phpUnit on a integration server to run all tests and if I launch phpunit command from the command line, I receive:

```
PHPUnit 3.2.18 by Sebastian Bergmann.
F..III..I......I.IIII...
Time: 6 seconds
There was 1 failure:

1) Warning(PHPUnit_Framework_Warning)
No tests found in class "TU".
FAILURES
Tests: 24, Failures: 1, Incomplete: 9.
```

Via apache, running the same test file:

```
PHPUnit 3.2.18 by Sebastian Bergmann.
..III..I......I.IIII...
Time: 7 seconds

OK, but incomplete or skipped tests!
Tests: 23, Incomplete: 9.
```

My TU class just include all tests classes with a `$suite->addTestFile()`,
and which have two static functions: `main()` which run all the tests,
and `suite()` which return the tests suite.
But the TU class is not in the primary file given as parameter to
phpunit command, it's a generic class which scan files and list all test
class.

I have the same problem with a class which extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase to add `specific assert()`, which is not included via `$suite->addTestFile()` but only by a `require()`.

How can I correct this?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

For the class wich extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase, it should be abstract, and the warning disapear.
For the first problem, it seems it is a bug.

Comment: I started getting this after upgrading from 3.x to 4.8 - but only when run via a testsuite. Your solution resolved it - Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using two different `php.ini` files for command line and Apache.

On most unixoid systems, running

```
diff /etc/php*/*/php.ini
```

should show you the differences.

On Windows systems, use the search to find files named `php.ini`. In most cases, you can just copy the Apache configuration file to the CLI one.

Comment: I don't think so.

dev@devweb/~ php -i | grep php.ini
Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /etc
Loaded Configuration File => /etc/php.ini

phpinfo() via apache : 
Loaded Configuration File /etc/php.ini

I actually think it's a phpunit issue.